# PubNub unsubscribe isn't firing presence event

Tags: javascript, pubnub, user-presence

I'm using the latest JavaScript API for PubNub, with presence switched on in the admin interface. I'm running two clients on a channel, initialized and subscribed like this:

```
pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
                publish_key   : 'xxx',
                subscribe_key : 'xxx',
                origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com',
                cipher_key    : 'xxx',
                ssl           : 'true',
                uuid          : uuid
            });

pubnub.subscribe({
                channel : CHANNEL,
                callback : function (message) {
                    $("#box").val($("#box").val() + message + "\r\n");
                },
                connect:    function () { console.log("Connected"); users(); },
                disconnect: function () { console.log("Disconnected"); },
                reconnect:  function () { console.log("Reconnected"); },
                error:      function () { console.log("Network Error"); },
                presence:   function (m) { console.log("Presence: " + m); }
            });
```

I unsubscribe from the channel like this:

```
function unsubscribe() {
    pubnub.unsubscribe({
        channel:    CHANNEL
    });
    console.log("Unsubscribed");
};
```

When clients join the channel, I see `join` presence actions in all clients that are subscribed. When clients timeout, I see those actions too.

When I call `unsubscribe()` the log line prints, and that client does not receive any more messages published on the channel, but there is **no `leave` presence action received** by other clients who are still subscribed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi!  Which SDK are you using?  Also your account needs to be configured for this so let us know at support@pubnub.com so we can configure your account!

Comment: Ensure you are on the latest SDK or if you are on an older account/SDK version we can setup for you a special config mode.  Make sure to contact us directly if you need our help configuring your account.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, when I tried to subscribe this morning I got a 400 Invalid error. When I investigated, the PubNub admin screen told me that there were no keys associated with my project.

When I had regenerated the keys I could subscribe - and the join and leave events worked as expected too. I now get the response I expect from here-now as well.

Odd, but fixed!

Comment: Hi, this may have been a web-session error you are seeing which is separate from the core global message bus system.  Your messages will be delivered as normal regardless!  :-)